# trying to connect from ionic to server but receive error

Tags: c#, asp.net, ionic-framework

I'm running my ionic app and when tried to connect to the server I got an Error above(in the title) what can I do?

This is the code that calls the server:

```
getcategories(): any {
    return this.http.get("http://172.20.10.6:52093/api/Categories/")
        .toPromise().then(
            res => { 
            this.cateroriesArr=res;
            console.log(res);
            return res;
        })
    .catch(err => { return false;})
}
```

Comment: please add error response from your browser, and also please make sure you are aware of CORS issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like:

in your app.module.ts

```
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'; // import HTTP library

imports: [
    BrowserModule, 
    HttpClientModule,  // inside your Imports array
    IonicModule.forRoot(), 
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
```

Import in your component.ts

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

constructor(private http: HttpClient) { 

}

this.http.get('https://someapi.com/posts').subscribe((response) => {
    console.log(response);
});
```

for complete Guide refer to :
[How to Call HTTP requests in Ionic](https://www.joshmorony.com/an-introduction-to-http-requests-fetching-data-in-ionic/)

Comment: While technically correct, I recommend you create a provider for this kind of API calls.

Comment: Right, But this is just a minimal example how to integrate HTTP requests.